# Ghostscript convert a PDF and output in a textfile

Tags: c#, pdf, text-files, ghostscript

1.I need to convert a PDF File into a txt.file. My Command seems to work, since i get the converted text on the screen, but somehow im incapable to direct the output into a textfile.

```
public static string[] GetArgs(string inputPath, string outputPath)
{ 
    return new[] {
                "-q", "-dNODISPLAY", "-dSAFER",
                "-dDELAYBIND", "-dWRITESYSTEMDICT", "-dSIMPLE",
                "-c", "save", "-f",
                "ps2ascii.ps", inputPath, "-sDEVICE=txtwrite",
                String.Format("-sOutputFile={0}", outputPath),
                "-c", "quit"
    }; 
}
```

2.Is there a unicode speficic .ps?

**Update:**
Posting my complete Code, maybe the error is somewhere else.

```
public static string[] GetArgs(string inputPath, string outputPath)
{
    return new[]    
    {   "-o c:/test.txt",    
        "-dSIMPLE",
        "-sFONTPATH=c:/windows/fonts",
        "-dNODISPLAY",
        "-dDELAYBIND",
        "-dWRITESYSTEMDICT",
        "-f",
        "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.05/lib/ps2ascii.ps",               
        inputPath,
    };
}

[DllImport("gsdll64.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_new_instance")]
private static extern int CreateAPIInstance(out IntPtr pinstance, IntPtr caller_handle);

[DllImport("gsdll64.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_init_with_args")]
private static extern int InitAPI(IntPtr instance, int argc, string[] argv);

[DllImport("gsdll64.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_exit")]
private static extern int ExitAPI(IntPtr instance);

[DllImport("gsdll64.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_delete_instance")]
private static extern void DeleteAPIInstance(IntPtr instance);`

private static object resourceLock = new object();

private static void Cleanup(IntPtr gsInstancePtr)
{
    ExitAPI(gsInstancePtr);
    DeleteAPIInstance(gsInstancePtr);
}

private static object resourceLock = new object();

public static void ConvertPdfToText(string inputPath, string outputPath) 
{ 
    CallAPI(GetArgs(inputPath, outputPath));
}

public static void ConvertPdfToText(string inputPath, string outputPath) 
{ 
    CallAPI(GetArgs(inputPath, outputPath));
}

private static void CallAPI(string[] args)      
{       
    // Get a pointer to an instance of the Ghostscript API and run the API with the current arguments       
    IntPtr gsInstancePtr;   
    lock (resourceLock)     
    {           
        CreateAPIInstance(out gsInstancePtr, IntPtr.Zero);      
        try
        {
            int result = InitAPI(gsInstancePtr, args.Length, args);                    
            if (result < 0)     
            {
                throw new ExternalException("Ghostscript conversion error", result);        
            }       
        }           
        finally     
        {               
            Cleanup(gsInstancePtr);     
        }       
    }   
}
```

Comment: Sorry... I didn't read your initial question close enough. Only a few minutes ago I realized that you are mixing two different, incompatible approaches: `ps2ascii.ps` is one, `DEVICE=txtwrite` is another. Seem my updated answer....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

2 questions, 2 answers:

1. To get output to a file, use `-sOutputFile=/path/to/file` on the commandline, or add the line

   ```
    "-sOutputFile=/where/it/should/go",
   ```

   to your `c#` code (can be the first argument, but should be before your first `"-c"`. But first get rid of your other `-sOutputFile` stuff you have already in there...  :-)
2. No, PostScript isn't aware of Unicode.

---

**Update**

*(Remark: Extracting text from PDF reliably is (for various technical reasons) notoriously difficult. And it may not work at all, whichever tool you try...)*

On the commandline, the following two should work for recent releases of Ghostscript (current version is v9.05). It would be your own job...

- ...to test which command works better for your use case, and
- ...to translate these into `c#` code.

### 1. `txtwrite` device:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
   -o c:/path/to/output.txt ^
   -dTextFormat=3 ^
   -sDEVICE=txtwrite ^
    input.pdf
```

**Notes:**

1. You may want to use `gswin64c.exe` (if available) on your system if it is 64bit.
2. The `-o` syntax for the output works only with recent versions of Ghostscript.
3. The `-o` syntax does implicitely also set the `-dBATCH` and `-dNOPAUSE` parameters.
4. If your Ghostscript is too old and the `-o` shorthand doesn't work, replace it with `-dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=...`.
5. Ghostscript can handle forward slashes inside path arguments even on Windows.
6. The `-dTextFormat` is by default set to `3` anyway, so it is not required here. 'Legal' values for it are:

   - `0` : This outputs XML-escaped Unicode along with info related to the format of the text (position, font name, point size, etc). Intended for developers only.
   - `1` : Same as `0`, but will output blocks of text.
   - `2` : This outputs Unicode (UCS2) text with BMO (Byte Order Mark); tries to approximate layout of text in original document.
   - `3` : **(default)** Same as `2`, but the text is encoded in UTF-8.
7. The `txtwrite` device with this `-dTextFormat` modifier is a rather new asset of Ghostscript, so please [report bugs](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/) if you find ones.

### 2. Using `ps2ascii.ps`

```
gswin32c.exe ^
   -sstdout=c:/path/to/output.txt ^
   -dSIMPLE ^
   -sFONTPATH=c:/windows/fonts ^
   -dNODISPLAY 
   -dDELAYBIND ^
   -dWRITESYSTEMDICT ^
   -f /path/to/ps2ascii.ps ^
    input.pdf
```

**Notes:**

1. This is a completely different method from the `txtwrite` device one and cannot be mixed with it!
2. `ps2ascii.ps` is a *file*, a PostScript program that Ghostscript invokes to extract the text. It is usually located in the Ghostscript installdir's `/lib` subdirectory. Go and see if it is really there.
3. `-dSIMPLE` may be replaced by `dCOMPLEX` in order to print out extra info lines (current color, presence of an image, rectangular fills).
4. `-sstdout=...` is required because the `ps2ascii.ps` PostScript program does print to stdout only and can't be told to write to a file. So `-sstdout=...` tells *Ghostscript* to redirect its stdout to a file.

### 3. Non-Ghostscript methods

Do not ignore other, non-Ghostscript methods that may be easier to work with. All of the following are cross-platform and should be available on Windows too:

- `mudraw -t`
  GPL licensed (or commercial, if you need). Commandline utility from [**MuPDF**](http://mupdf.com/) to extract text from PDF (which is developed by the same group of developers that do Ghostscript).
- `pdftotext`
  GPL licensed. Commandline utility from [**Poppler**](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) (which is a fork from [**XPDF**](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/index.html), that also provides a `pdftotext`).
- `podofotxtextract`
  GPL licensed. Commandline utility based the [**PoDoFo**](http://podofo.sf.net/) PDF processing library.
- **TET**
  The [*Text Extraction Toolkit*](http://www.pdflib.com/en/products/tet/) from PDFlib.com (commercial, but may be gratis for personal use -- I didn't check recent news). Probably the most powerful text extraction tool of them all...

Comment: Still doesn't work... 
"-sOutputFile=C:\\temp\\PDFs2\\test.txt", 
Added on first line of my arguments but no file, even though Ghostscript produces an output... any idea?

Comment: What's the complete code now? (You can update your original question...)

Comment: updated the question, tried it with and without "-sDEVICE=txtwrite" but it makes no difference.

Comment: I tried your example with ps2ascii.ps, but still it won't give me an output file. Got an Idea what else could be the tried out?

Comment: **HOW** did you try it? On the commandline, just like I said? Did it run without warnings or errors? What is the path to your ps2ascii.ps?  -- Which version of Ghostscript are you using?

Comment: ConvertPdfToText(@"C:\temp\PDFs2\DB_Remixer4500_DT_1106_HI.pdf", @"C:\test.txt"); was my method-call. The Second parameter is not important since i use "-o c:/test.txt".No warnings and no errors. I can see the converted text but no file is created. The path is "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.05/lib/ps2ascii.ps" as you can see from my latest update. I use Ghostscript 9.05. I'm about to give up, i dont know what might be the cause...

Comment: Ah... this `ps2ascii.ps` program doesn't follow the standard `-sOutputFile=` or `-o` conventions. I'll update my answer. You have to tell Ghostscript to write its standard output to a file then...

Comment: I tested the last version of my suggested commandline now and it works. You were right in that `-o out.txt` didn't work -- it requires `-sstdout=out.txt`!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had to use `-dTextFormat=2` or I was getting random characters (Chinese). Not sure if it's my PDF, but an older version of Ghostscript installed on my Mac does not required this flag.