# Ghostscript converting pdf to text file, output is unreadable

Tags: pdf, ascii, ghostscript

I was trying to convert a pdf document into text file. everything works until i open the output file to see its unreadable the characters are in some Chinese font

"       琀攀猀琀 "

this is my command line

```
gswin64c.exe -ps2ascii -sDEVICE=txtwrite -sOutputFile=outputtext.txt test.pdf
```

im i doing something wrong?

Comment: I would attempt to resubmit this asking about `gswin64` and `ghostscript` instead. Your python code is just passing the string to the shell.

Comment: it's not a python problem! have you tried the command line alone?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yea i tried it in command line as well but same result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ghostscript convert a PDF and output in a textfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754556/ghostscript-convert-a-pdf-and-output-in-a-textfile)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't posted the file, so its not possible to be absolutely certain, however....

Almost certainly the text in your PDF file is not encoded using an ASCII encoding scheme (possibly contains sunset fonts), and does not contain a ToUnicode CMap for the font in question. Additionally the glyph names are not standard names (or its a TrueType font, which don't have named glyphs).

Without any of the above information txtwrite doesn't have any clue what the character codes represent, and so simply emits them verbatim.

Given that you are seeing Chinese glyphs, I would suspect that the original font is a CIDFont, probably a TrueType font, subset and has no ToUnicode CMap.

In this case, the only way to get the text out will be to use OCR.